# Show that an initial dual feasible solution is always present.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex

Given the problem
$$ \text{Minimize} \ \ \ \ c \cdot x \\
\text{subject to} \ \ \ \ Ax \leq b \\
x \geq 0, \ c \geq 0$$

show that an initial dual feasible solution is always present.

I know that the above minimum program can always be rewritten as the following dual program:

$$ \text{Maximize} \ \ \ \ b \cdot w \\
\text{subject to} \ \ \ \ A^Tw \leq c \\
w \ \ \text{unrestricted}$$

That's all I have at the moment. I don't see how this can tell me anything. Am I missing some important theorems?

Comment: What about $w = 0$?

Comment: Your dual is incorrect. Could you derive the right dual first? Also, $c$ in the primal is not a variable.